# How to link to source document/article

Tags: org-mode

I often create short articles for myself, which are mostly extracts from other articles on the Web.  For such articles I usually add a source link simply like this:

```
[[http://example.com/article][Source]]
```

Is there an “official” way to do this, like a property or `#+` keyword?  If it reflects in exported files (I use HTML and rarely Markdown), the better.

Comment: what are you looking for the link you use doesn't provide? It would show in exported files as a hyperlink.

Comment: It does, it actually works, too. I'm just curious if there is a more sophisticated way to do this (like bibliography entries in a research paper, just for one link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using the code below to set a `SOURCE` property on captures.  If you add `:source t` to the template then the `SOURCE` property will set to the captures `:annotation` (the same as the `%a` template parameter).  A nice accidental features is that `C-c C-o` will find this link in the org file or the agenda.

```
(defvar org-source-property "SOURCE"
  "The property used to store the source of the capture.")

(defvar org-capture-default-source :annotation
  "The default org-capture property to get the source from.")

(defun org-capture-source-process-source (source)
  "Process the input SOURCE into a string.

This is called by `org-capture-set-source' just before passing
the result into `org-set-property'.  It must return a string."
  (format "%s" source))

(defun org-capture-set-source (&optional source global)
  "Set the source of a captured item.

If the input argument SOURCE is provided and non-nil, set the
source to that. Otherwise look at the :source property of
`org-capture-plist' are parse it as follows.

    If :source is nil do nothing.
    If :source is a string take that as the source.
    If :source is a form evaluate it and take that as the source.
    If :source is just t, use the default property (`org-capture-default-source')
    Otherwise assume it is property and look it up in `org-capture-plist'.

This function is intended to be called from
`org-capture-before-finalize-hook' where
`org-capture-current-plist' is still valid. To use the global
capture date instead, set GLOBAL to t."

  (let* ((local (not global))
         (source (or source (org-capture-get :source local)))
         )
    (when source
      (org-set-property org-source-property
                        (org-capture-source-process-source
                         (cond ((stringp source) source)
                               ((listp source) (eval source))
                               ((eq source t) (org-capture-get
                                               org-capture-default-source
                                               local))
                               (t (org-capture-get source local))
                               ))))
    ))

(add-hook 'org-capture-before-finalize-hook #'org-capture-set-source)
```

Answer (score 4):

If citations and bibliographies are what you want, see org-ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2t925KRBbFc and https://melpa.org/#/org-ref. You can make bibtex entries for the articles you want to cite, and use org-ref to insert nice links to them.

Comment: It’s definitely not citations. It is somewhat bibliography, except there is only one source, as my whole headline content is an excerpt from an article. I’ll take a look at org-ref tomorrow, thanks!